# IOS : sending large data of video

Tags: ios, swift, image, udp

I have problem with large data of CMSampleBuffer when sending to my server.

I have an app where I capture video output. I want to sent the CMSampleBuffer to my server using udp packets. When I first convert my sampleBuffer to a UIImage in PNG format I notice the image is about 3 or 4 Megabytes long.
In udp you can only sent about 64K max data in one go.

Does anyone has an idea how I can stream this video data on my server ?.
Do I have to split my sampleBuffer in chunks for say about 10K ?

Thanks

John